# Regarding the window.after() finction in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, delay

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

def function_example():
    a= 2
```

My question is what is the difference between these two following code executions, and why are they producing different results?

Scenario 1:

```
window.after(1000, function_example)
```

VS.

Scenario 2:

```
window.after(1000)
function_example()
```

I thought both should produce the same outcome, but they are producing different outcomes.

Comment: The only difference between them is that in the first case, you can still interact with the application within that second; however in the second case, you cannot.

Comment: It worked for Python 3.12.1. Both produced the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps easier to understand with a slightly different example.

```
import tkinter as tk 

window = tk.Tk() 
  
def function_example( note ): 
    print( note ) 
 
window.after( 5000, function_example, 'Called from after' ) 

function_example('1st call outside after.')

window.after( 1000 )   # Stops execution of the GUI for 1 second

function_example( '2nd call outside after.' ) 
  
window.mainloop()
```

Results are

```
1st call outside after.  # Prints as the GUI is being created
2nd call outside after.  # Prints 1 second after that
Called from after        # 5 seconds after the GUI is created
```

No python code is processed for 1 second after the `after` method is called without a callback function being specified.

The GUI window opening as the '2nd call outside after.' is printed helps to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 0):

`after` with a single argument arguments works exactly like `time.sleep` - it will cause the program to freeze for the given duration. Tkinter is not able to respond to any events during that time, including events that tell it to redraw the window. When the given time period has expired, the function will return and any following code can continue.

`after` called with two or more arguments will add the second argument on a queue to be run after a delay given as the first parameter. In this case, the call to `after` returns immediately and your application will continue executing. As soon as possible after the given delay has elapsed, the function will be run.